# Order the tableview cell by the subtitle

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, mapkit

i'm getting the distance of 2 points like this

```
[userLocation distanceFromLocation: annotationLocation] / 1000;
```

and setting this to the subtitle of a tableview like the image bellow
[image: screenshot]

the question is, can i order this table by the distances (subtitle)?

Thanks!

and sorry for the bad english =x

Comment: Douglas, which solution did you end up using?  Are you using CoreData?

Comment: ferostar solution works for me. I'm using .plist file.
userlocation and annotationLocation are both CLLocation.
So i used -initWithLatitude:longitude: and -distanceFromLocation: to get the distances and sort it on a NSArray.

Comment: Perhaps it would be best to chat but I have the array of locations with lat and long.  I calculate the distance from userLocation to each location.  So I have all the data, so what do I put in the new array?  Here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14845434/how-do-i-sort-table-cells-from-core-data

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can order your UITableView's cells any way to want to, but you have to do it before showing them, when you create the table's data source. If you use an NSFetchResultsController, you can put the distance as the sort descriptor. And if you are using a simple NS(Mutable)Array, sort it before making it the table's source.

Like Chris said, you can do it with

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"annotationLocation" ascending:YES];
```

If it is an NSArray what you are using, then:

```
[arrayOfObjects sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter];
```

and if it is an NSFetchResultsController:

```
NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:titleSorter, nil];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
```

Comment: but annotationLocation is not in the database.  I have lat and long.

Answer (score 1):

Create an NSSortDescriptor to sort your rows:

```
NSSortDescriptor *titleSorter= [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"annotationLocation" ascending:YES];
[arrayOfObjects sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:titleSorter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Make an array with these distances, order it how you want and

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cellIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *_cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (_cell == nil) {
        _cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }
    _cell.textLabel.text = @"Transcripts";
    _cell.detailTextLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return _cell;
}
```

well, something like that should do the trick.

Hope it helps

Comment: In my CD database I only have latitude and longitude.  Currently the locations are sorted by date like so: `
            
            [request setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:
                                         [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES]]];
            self.dates = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            `

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some certain objects holding a coordinate and put the objects in to an array locations, you can use a comparator block by doing:

```
locations = [locations sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id a, id b) {

    CLLocationDistance dist_a= [[a objectsForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: userPosition];
    CLLocationDistance dist_b= [[b objectsForKey:@"coordinate"] distanceFromLocation: userPosition];
    if ( dist_a < dist_b ) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedAscending;
    } else if ( dist_a > dist_b) {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedDescending;
    } else {
        return (NSComparisonResult)NSOrderedSame;
    }
}
```

You add this code to your `viewWillAppear:` to get updated locations each time you display the tableView.